# $\mathbb{C}$ is algebraic over $K$ .True/false

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

Is the following  statement is true/false

> Let $K$ be the smallest subfield of $\mathbb{C}$ containing all the roots of unity then $\mathbb{C}$ is algebraic over $K$

My attempt  :  I this think  statement  is true

Take =$\mathbb Q(\sqrt d)$ is the smallest subfield of $\mathbb C$

then $\mathbb{C}$ is algebraic over $K$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $K$ is algebraic over $\mathbb{Q}$ , $\overline{K} = \overline{\mathbb{Q}}$. Therefore, any element in $\mathbb{C}$ that is transcendental over $\mathbb{Q}$ will also be transcendental over $\mathbb{K}$.

Comment: Im not getting what is  value  of  $\overline{K}=\overline{\mathbb{Q}}?$

Comment: Anything outside of $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$ is also outside of $\overline{K}$.